# MySQL update query within condition

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to use one update query as a condition in another (update) query?

**If so**- What is the syntax for it?

**If not** -  Do you think there is a reason behind it? Preventing bad practices maybe, or just the lack of need of this feature?

I'm not having a problem, per-say, I just want to know if it is possible. I came across this while trying to help someone else's question using only one query (seemed more interesting at the moment).

[My queries on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc7000)

**What did I try:**  (in the example I'm trying to update one field to primary only if the update query in the condition changed at least one row, but I mostly care about the syntax so never mind if that's what's actually happening).

1. using IF:

   ```
   UPDATE `data` SET `priority` = 
       IF (
           UPDATE `data` SET `status` ='deleted',`priority` = NULL WHERE (`id_fk` = 1 AND `priority` = 'PRIMARY' AND `status`='active'),
           'PRIMARY',`priority`) 
   WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id_fk` = 1 AND `status` = 'active';
   ```

Which results in error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'UPDATE `data` SET `status` ='deleted',`priority` = NULL WHERE (`id_fk` = 1 AND `' at line 6:
```

2. using CASE WHEN:

   ```
   UPDATE `data` SET `priority` = (CASE
       WHEN UPDATE `data` SET `status` ='deleted',`priority` = NULL WHERE (`id_fk` = 1 AND `priority` = 'PRIMARY' AND `status`='active') > 0 THEN 'PRIMARY'
       ELSE `priority`
       END)
   WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id_fk` = 1 AND `status` = 'active';
   ```

Which results in error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
 'UPDATE `data` SET `status` ='deleted',`priority` = NULL WHERE (`id_fk` = 1 AND `' at line 2:
```

And some more variants on those two.

Just in case you can't access sqlfiddle - my queries:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
 `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_fk` int(13) NOT NULL,
 `priority` enum('PRIMARY'),
 `status` enum('active','deleted'),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `prime_address` (`id_fk`,`priority`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `data` (`id_fk`,`priority`,`status`) values 
('1',NULL,'active'),
('1',NULL,'active'),
('1','PRIMARY','active'),
('1',NULL,'active'),('1',NULL,'active'),
('1',NULL,'deleted');

#If query:
#inner query test:
#UPDATE `data` SET `status` ='deleted',`priority` = NULL WHERE (`id_fk` = 1 AND `priority` = 'PRIMARY' AND `status`='active');

#outer query test:
#UPDATE `data` SET `priority` = IF(true,'PRIMARY',`priority`) WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id_fk` = 1 AND `status` = 'active'

UPDATE `data` SET `priority` = 
IF (
  UPDATE `data` SET `status` ='deleted',`priority` = NULL WHERE (`id_fk` = 1 AND `priority` = 'PRIMARY' AND `status`='active'),
  'PRIMARY',`priority`) 
WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id_fk` = 1 AND `status` = 'active';

#CASE WHEN query test:

UPDATE `data` SET `priority` = (CASE
    WHEN 1 > 0 THEN 'PRIMARY'
    ELSE `priority`
    END)
WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id_fk` = 1 AND `status` = 'active';

#CASE WHEN query:
UPDATE `data` SET `priority` = (CASE
    WHEN UPDATE `data` SET `status` ='deleted',`priority` = NULL WHERE (`id_fk` = 1 AND `priority` = 'PRIMARY' AND `status`='active') > 0 THEN 'PRIMARY'
    ELSE `priority`
    END)
WHERE `id` = 1 AND `id_fk` = 1 AND `status` = 'active';
```

Comment: You can't use an `UPDATE` statement in another query because it doesn't return anything. Only `SELECT` queries return something.

Comment: @Barmar I've read in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) that update queries return the number of rows affected (i.e.`UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed`)

Comment: It's just talking about what it returns in an API, it doesn't actually have a value in SQL itself.

Comment: @Barmar oh, I probably misunderstood. Thanks, I guess this question is pretty silly then.